# Paging Library recyclerview does not display updated data (DB + Network)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-paging-library

I have a list of persons to show using Paging Library, load the initial data from the local DB, and once it's required more data, I call the API to fetch from the server and save it into the DB.

My Fragment:

```
Class PersonListFragment: Fragment(){

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
      recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
      recycler_view.adapter = personListAdapter

      personListViewModel.getPersonsLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
         personListAdapter.submitList(it)
      })
   }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
class PersonViewModel: ViewModel{

   lateinit var personsLiveData: LiveData<PagedList<Person>>
   lateinit var boundaryCallback: TransactionBoundaryCallback

   fun getPersonsLiveData(): LiveData<PagedList<Person>> = personsLiveData

   Init {
      val dataSourceFactory = getPersons()
      val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setPageSize(10)
            .build()

      boundaryCallback = PersonBoundaryCallback()

      personsLiveData = LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, config)
            .setBoundaryCallback(boundaryCallback)
            .build()
   }

   private fun getPersons(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Persons> = personDAO.getAllPersons()

}
```

The list adapter:

```
class PersonListAdapter: PagedListAdapter<Person, PersonListAdapter.PersonViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {
   ...

   companion object {

      val DIFF_CALLBACK: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Person> = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Person>() {

         override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Person, newItem: Person): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
         }

         override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Person, newItem: Person): Boolean {
             return oldItem == newItem
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface PersonDAO {
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   fun insert(persons: List<Person>): Completable

   @androidx.room.Persons
   @Query("Select * from person_table")
   fun getAllPersons(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Person>
}
```

Callback class:

```
class PersonBoundaryCallback: PagedList.BoundaryCallback<Person>(){

   override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
      requestAndSave()
      super.onZeroItemsLoaded()
   }

   override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: Person) {
        ...
      //request data from API and saves it into DB
      requestAndSave()
      super.onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd)

   }
}
```

Until here is all good (the data fetched is saved into db), but the recyclerview does not update the list with the new data, instead it keeps displaying only the initial one

I have searched about this topic and adapt it to it, but so far cannot find why is not working for me.

Comment: u may want to refer this tutorial with sample implementation, remember to replace android.arch.paging... (deprecated) with androidx.paging... package (jetpack). Hope this helps ! https://medium.com/@harunwangereka/android-paging-library-with-kotlin-coroutines-b96602e3fae3

Comment: Thank you, will check it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry answering late, but got busy. I found the answer very clear in Android's page [DataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource) (deprecated):

> "A PagedList / DataSource pair are a snapshot of the data set. A new
>   pair of PagedList / DataSource must be created if an update occurs,
>   such as a reorder, insert, delete, or content update occurs. A
>   DataSource must detect that it cannot continue loading its snapshot
>   (for instance, when Database query notices a table being invalidated),
>   and call invalidate(). Then a new PagedList / DataSource pair would be
>   created to load data from the new state of the Database query."

Therefore, my data gets updated once the refresh is called by swiping the list down.